# How to disable toolbar buttons during page transition?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using an [external toolbar](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/toolbar-fixed-external/) in a jQuery Mobile site I'm working on. I initialize it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']").toolbar();
});
```

I have a couple of buttons in the toolbar and want to disable them during page transitions so users don't click them multiple times which seems to get the framework into a weird state. My first attempt has been to listen for the `pagebeforeshow` and `pageshow` events to programmatically disable and enable the buttons:

```
$(function() {
    $("[data-role='header'], [data-role='footer']").toolbar({
        create: function (event, ui) {
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
                $('#page-header .ui-btn').button('disable');
            });

            $(document).on('pageshow', function () {
                $('#page-header .ui-btn').button('enable');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I have the code nested inside like that because I don't want to register the handlers until the toolbar has been initialized. However, I'm running into a separate problem:

`Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'`

Since I'm not explicitly initializing the buttons myself, I'm not sure I understand how / where I can wait for them to be initialized.

Is there a better approach to this, and does anyone have any suggestions to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.button()` on `input` with type button, reset and submit. For anchor or button tag you need to add / remove `ui-state-disabled` class.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforehide", function () {
  $('#page-header .ui-btn').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
});

$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
  $('#page-header .ui-btn').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/syPw4/)**

Comment: Thanks, this worked! However I wasn't able to use `pagecontainerbeforehide` or `pagecontainershow`, and don't see them listed in the [API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).

Comment: @Brian they are new, non-announced yet they should work as long as you use jQM 1.4. check console on this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/syPw4/1/).